# Factorize $999999$ into a product of irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (clarification)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Factorize $999999$ into a product of irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

First I factorized $999999$ into a product of primes in $\mathbb{Z}$ as follows
Factorize $999999$ into a product of irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

First I factorized $999999$ into a product of primes in $\mathbb{Z}$ as follows

$999999 = 3^3\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot37$

From here I see that $37 = (6+i)(6-i)$

Now we have $999999 = 3^3\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13\cdot(6+i)(6-i)$

Then $13 = (2-3i)(2+3i)$

So $999999 = 3^3\cdot7\cdot11\cdot(2-3i)(2+3i)\cdot(6+i)(6-i)$

I see that $3, 7,$ and $11$ are congruent to $3 \pmod 4$ so these integers are prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

So I want to know if I have completed the problem because $3, 7,$ and $11$ are irreducible; or if there is more work to do.

Comment: Do you mean $13 = (2+3i)(2-3i)?$

Comment: Sorry about that, just fixed up an egregious serious of typos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are finished. The factors are [irreducible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element) and the factorization is even unique (up to the order of the elements and units)  because the [Gaussian integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) are a [unique factorization domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain). A characterization of the irreducible elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer#As_a_principal_ideal_domain).